# How to upload a file with metadata map wrapped in DTO?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, testing, file-upload

I am trying to expose an endpoint to upload a file with metadata map. I want to have it in one POJO - see `ConvertFileRequest` below. I cannot pass `metadata` as json to the request parameter map in `@WebMvcTest` because "`no matching editors or conversion strategy found`". Is it because `@WebMvcTest` is not configuring some converters? Am I using the `mockMvc` incorrectly? Or is there something else I am missing in the design? Or is there a way to put all the remaining params in the `metadata` field without json serialisation?

The mentioned test:

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@WebMvcTest(controllers = FileFormatConvertController.class)
class FileFormatConvertControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    void shouldUploadFileWithMetadata() throws Exception {
        MockMultipartFile file = new MockMultipartFile(
                "file",
                "file.docx",
                MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE,
                "file content".getBytes()
        );
        mockMvc.perform(multipart("/file")
                                .file(file)
                                .param("title", "File title")
                                .param("metadata", new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(Map.of("some-value", "some-key")))
                )
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

Fails with:

```
Resolved [org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'convertFileRequest' on field 'metadata': rejected value [{"some-value":"some-key"}]; codes [typeMismatch.convertFileRequest.metadata,typeMismatch.metadata,typeMismatch.java.util.Map,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [convertFileRequest.metadata,metadata]; arguments []; default message [metadata]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Map' for property 'metadata'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Map' for property 'metadata': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]]
```

---

The rest of the code:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/file")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class FileFormatConvertController {

    @PostMapping
    ResponseEntity<ConvertFileResponse> convertFile(@Valid @ModelAttribute final ConvertFileRequest request) {
       return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }
```

```
@Data
public class ConvertFileRequest {
    @NotNull
    private MultipartFile file;
    @NotEmpty
    private String title;
    private Map<String, String> metadata;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as suggestion  , it may better to use `@RequestPart` instead of `@ModelAttribute`;
divide file in individual part , and fileMeta in aother ;
here is code snippet ,

- route

```
    @PostMapping("/upload/file")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> convertFile( @RequestPart("file") FilePart filePart, @RequestPart(required = false,value = "meta") ConvertFileRequest request) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }
```

- entity

```
@Data
public class ConvertFileRequest {

    private String title;
    private String name;
    private Map<String, String> metadata;

}
```

note that , the args `file` content-type shoulf be `multipart/form-data` , and `meta` should define as `application/json`